# Como modificar la forma de una imagen en flutter

Tags: flutter

[image]

como pueden ver en la primera pantalla, hay una imagen de un faro, es posible dar esa forma recortada
irregularmente con Flutter?

(soy nuevo)

Comment: te refieres a recortar la imagen de esa forma diagonal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El corte lo puedes hacer con el widget `ClipPath` y `CustomClipper`.

De la siguiente manera:

```dart
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Expanded(
            child: ClipPath(
              clipper: _MyClipper(),
              child: Container(
                color: Colors.blue,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: Container(
              color: Colors.white,
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class _MyClipper extends CustomClipper<Path> {
  @override
  Path getClip(Size size) {
    return Path()
      ..lineTo(0.0, size.height)
      ..lineTo(size.width, size.height - 50)
      ..lineTo(size.width, 0.0)
      ..close();
  }

  @override
  bool shouldReclip(covariant CustomClipper oldClipper) => false;
}
```

Resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Te recomiendo este tutorial donde puedes encontrar más info sobre los Clippers:  https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-custom-clipper-28c6d380fdd6

Comment: hola diego una consulta, que es esta syntax?

Comment: `return Path() ..lineTo()`

Comment: Es el operador de cascada, es la sintaxis para simplificar código. Es lo mismo que final path = Path();     path.lineTo(..);  return path;   te dejo este link : https://www.w3adda.com/dart-tutorial/dart-cascade-notation y no te olvide de seguir mi canal de flutter :  youtube.com/diegoveloper :D

Comment: nuevo sub! gracias por la ayuda, soy nuevo en flutter vengo de react